# how to find Due Date on excel formulas?

Tags: excel, date

How to add `DUE DATE`, counting start from table `INVOICE DATE` in Microsoft Office Excel ?

I don't know how to using this formula, but I got some hints :

1. if an **invoices** start date between **2-15 per months**, due date automatically filled date **15** `next month`
   Examples:
   **`INVOICE DATE`** | **`DUE DATE`**  *format (D-M-Y)*
   ---------------------------------
   `11/08/2019` | `15/09/2019`
   `15/08/2019` | `15/09/2019`
   `02/09/2019` | `15/10/2019`
2. if an **invoices** start date between **16-31 per months** and date **1st** next month, due date automatically filled date **1** every `2 next months`
   Examples:
   **`INVOICE DATE`** | **`DUE DATE`**  *format (D-M-Y)*
   ---------------------------------
   `21/08/2019` | `01/10/2019`
   `16/08/2019` | `01/10/2019`
   `01/09/2019` | `01/10/2019`
   `01/12/2019` | `01/01/2020`
   `30/12/2019` | `01/02/2020`

what should I do, prefer on `table A` or `table B` ? for easy to use ?
[fixed image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ7By.jpg)

or you can download it here *[-> Google Drive(Fixed)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zro9_54Cn50SewX34u6ZqWcTVaAY_UYr/view?usp=sharing)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one (the invoice date is in cell A1 here):

```
=IF(AND(DAY(A1)<16,DAY(A1)>1),DATE(YEAR(EOMONTH(A1,1)),MONTH(EOMONTH(A1,1)),15),DATE(YEAR(EOMONTH(A1,2)),MONTH(EOMONTH(A1,2)),1))
```

Comment: first think, thank you man i appreciate it. thank for answering my question. so i think i made a mistake on images file. https://prnt.sc/x9jgst.

Comment: example : every date `16 November 2019 - 1 Desember 2019` = Due date ( `1 January 2020` )

Comment: you can download it from here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zro9_54Cn50SewX34u6ZqWcTVaAY_UYr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i tried several time it works on date `2 - 31 every months`, but on date `1st` should be due date `+1 month`, not `+2 months` (sorry, my mistaken here)

Comment: it should be : invoice date : `1 August 2010` - due date `1 September 2010`

Comment: Can you re-entry new answer sir ? your answer is fine and works well in my excel formulas. but only at `1st` date it won't work as well

Comment: =IF(AND(DAY(B6)>=2,DAY(B6)<=15),EOMONTH(B6,0)+15,EOMONTH(B6-1,1)+1) . it works well for me. thank you Mr. Max

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula. You have to format the resulting cell as date format.

```
=IF(AND(DAY(A2)>=2,DAY(A2)<=15),DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2+1),15),DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+2,1))
```

[image]

Comment: oh thank you man for answering my question. but i do little mistake here. i fixed my image.

Comment: overall your answer is right. but every date 1st  is wrong. on your ms excel, B7 cell should be `01-10-2019`. not `01-11-2019`

Comment: you can download it from here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zro9_54Cn50SewX34u6ZqWcTVaAY_UYr/view?usp=sharing